# Pull a table from a web query according to an input

Tags: excel, vba

The original macro looks like this:

```
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 0 (2)", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://www.reuters.com/companies/luv/financials/income-statement-annual""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{"""", type text}, {""31-Dec-19"", type number}, {""31-Dec-18"", type number}, {""31-Dec-17"", type text}, {""31-Dec-16"", type text}, {""31-Dec-15"", type tex" & _
        "t}, {""Trend"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=""Table 0 (2)"";Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Table 0 (2)]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_0__2"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Essentially this macro pulls a table from a excel web query from a specific URL (https://www.reuters.com/companies/luv/financials/income-statement-annual). The idea was I wanted to replace luv within the URL with a string variable so I could pull a table from many different sources depending on which URL I wanted to pull data from. I edited my macro to look like this (ticker is the string variable):

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Table 0 (2)", Formula:= _
            "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents(""https://www.reuters.com/companies/""&ticker&""/financials/income-statement-annual""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Data0,{{"""", type text}, {""31-Dec-19"", type number}, {""31-Dec-18"", type number}, {""31-Dec-17"", type text}, {""31-Dec-16"", type text}, {""31-Dec-15"", type tex" & _
            "t}, {""Trend"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
```

But when I do that I get a Run-time error '424': Object required on this line:

```
.ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_0__2"
```

The macro obviously works flawlessly before I attempt to modify the URL with a string variable. And I have checked, the URL's are identical except for (in this case) the name of the company which is what my string variable is supposed to represent. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looking at your `Name:=Table 0 (2)`, you may have duplicates name and information. Does your macro fails when all previous connection have been cleared and removed ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No the macro continues to work without any previous connections. I even opened a brand new excel worksheet and used the macro there with no problems.

Comment: I think we need more info about how you are deploying with variable for ticker. It should fail with warning that query with name Table 0 (2) already exists if you try to re-run with a new ticker without removing the existing table and connection. You are better testing for if connection/table exists and then simply alter the url and querytable refresh (or connection refresh) if it does rather than attempt to add.